# getting error while importing excel data into mysql using python only one row inserted

Tags: python

I am trying to import excel data into MySQL using Python with the help of video tutorial but I have the following issue:

only the first row in a excel file was inserted into mysql and getting the following error

```
cursor.execute(query, values) line 179 in execute
```

here is my code

```
import xlrd
import MySQLdb
book=xlrd.open_workbook("C:\Python27\mygdata.xls")
sheet=book.sheet_by_name("Sheet1")

database=MySQLdb.connect(host="Localhost", user="root", passwd="sharan246", db="test1")
cursor=database.cursor()
query=""" INSERT INTO omrdata (regno,name,subject,barcode,flag1) values (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"""
for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    regno = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
    name= sheet.cell(r, 1).value
    subject=sheet.cell(r, 2).value
    barcode=sheet.cell(r, 3).value
    flag1=sheet.cell(r, 4).value
    values=(regno,name,subject,barcode,flag1)
    cursor.execute(query, values)
    cursor.close()
    database.commit()
    database.close()
    print ""
    print "All done bye for now"
    print ""
    columns=str(sheet.ncols)
    print"i Just Imported"
```

Comment: All the lines after `cursor.execute(...)` should be outside the `for` loop. You are closing the connection and database just after inserting the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You close cursor `cursor.close()` as well as `database.close()` inside for loop but open it up only once at the beginning.  Try moving those lines outside of for loop and see if it's going to help.

Comment: Thanks You so Much Sir

Comment: sir if you dont mind one more question how do i get count of imported records

Comment: @sharankumar check out `cursor.rowcount`  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#rowcount